# Does While true loop always cause Out of memory error?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I always thought that a while (true) {...Any code..} would always result in a out of memory error.

But as I go deeper in java it seems it might not be like that.

I'm not able to confirm but if we have a while true that only does calculations, We are not expected to have an out of memory error, only a very detrimental cpu performance, right?
On the other hand if we are always requiring more memory it is expected to have a out of memory error.

I've 3 cases below.

1. calculations only (I think no memory is being allocated under the hood)
2. Ever increasing arraylist which it looks an obvious out of memory error
3. always instanting arraylist with new keyword. I dont know if it causes an out of memory error, because of garbage collector.

I'm not testing im my pc because I only have one, hope someone has the knowledge.

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloLeak{

     //calculations only, MemoryLeak?
     public static void outofmemo1(){
        long i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            i = i * i;
        }
     }
    
     //adding infinite number of objects, memory leak confirmed.
     public static void outofmemo2(){
        int i = 0;
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true)
        {
            l.add(i);
        }
     }
    
     //Creating infinite number of ArrayList objects, will garbage collector clear the unused objects or we will get memory leak?
     public static void outofmemo3(){
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true)
        {
            l = new ArrayList<>();
        }
     }
     
     public static void main(String []args){
        outofmemo1();
        //outofmemo2();
        //outofmemo3(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: "if we are always requiring more memory it is expected to have a memory leak" you keep using those words, "memory leak". I don't think they mean what you think they mean.

Comment: "I'm not testing im my pc because I only have one" - you think a memory leak shreds your PC?

Comment: @maloomeister well, if your memory leaks all over your motherboard it could short-circuit something. /s

Comment: @maloomeister I'm not afraid of a memory leak, but I'm afraid of an over consuming cpu program that can block all my programs and eventually burn something. So the worry is to mistakenly create a program that runs an infinite cycle and the only solution is to forcely shutdown my pc to avoid something worst. (It have happened once)

Comment: Computer programs can't 'block all your programs' on any operating system more sophisticated than say Windows 3.0, let alone 'burn something'.  There is no basis whatsoever for your stated belief that all `while (true)` loops cause memory leaks.Try to be realistic please.

Comment: Hi @FedericoklezCulloca, you re right I'm misusing the word. sorry about that. It is not a memory leak but a out of memory error. because the program would consume too much memory. Memory Leak would be caused if I had unaccesable objects that are not removed from memory I think. Let me fix the Title and text

Comment: 1. Will do absolutly nothing except ending in an endless loop. 2. Will crash with an OutOfMemoryError, because you add always a new element to the list, until the heap is filled. 3. Will be like 1. but you may have spikes up to for example 2GB, then the GC will come, it will spike again, and so on.

Comment: Hi @MarquisofLorne, so you are saying I can't have a program that consumes so much CPU that all programs get super sluggish? Are you saying that if your PC is too hot, and you are running intensive applications, you can't burn something? Thank you for you intervention but what you are saying does not make sense to me. The memory leak wording was a tecnical wording mistake that @ FedericoklezCulloca pointed out very well. I think you can add value to this discussion but would like to see you take a more humble and value based communication approach.

Comment: @JCWasmx86, that looks like an answer! So you are saying that in 3. We might not have a out of memory error because garbage collector might clean unused variables?

Comment: @Nelssen while a misbehaving program may very well make your system sluggish, it's very hard for a single-threaded program (like the one in your question) to block a whole (multi-core or multi-threading) CPU. So unless you're running on a i686 it won't lock your computer. About physical damage, if your CPU overheats to the point of causing damage, the problem is not with software, but the fact that your CPU is not properly cooled. Also, most CPUs usually shut down *before* any damage is done.

Comment: @Nelssen yes, they are not unused, but a new object is created every iteration. Sometimes the JVM runs the garbage collector, it sees that there are objects no other object has a reference too, and removes them.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that detail about multi-core/threading makes a lot of sense to me. Thank you :)

Comment: @JCWasmx86 alright, be free to write an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Will do absolutly nothing except ending in an endless loop.
2. Will crash with an OutOfMemoryError, because you add always a new element to the list, until the heap is filled.
3. Will be like 1. but you may have spikes up to for example 2GB, then the GC will come, see that there are unused objects, removes them. After that it will spike again, and so on